# Go to previous html page without refreshing the data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Am using onLoad function of html page to fetch the data from server and to update the table rows with angularJS ng-repeat. Whenever I go to another html page and returns back, onload function is executing and it causes a delay. I need to return to the previous html page without refreshing the data.

Comment: Can you explain how you are returning to the original page? Does a `window.history.back()` cause this behavior?

Comment: Put your data loading into an angular service and have your controller request it from the service.

Comment: This might be a hack, but it sounds like what you need. As long as you stay in the same domain you can use [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name), just put your data in there (as a string) and it is persisted: `window.name = '{x:10}'`;

Comment: This is for phonegap application and am using navigator.app.backhistory() to go back to the previous html page

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple of options -- the best one tends to be saving a flag inside of a `window.sessionStorage` and storing the data there as well.

Note that `sessionStorage` is unique to each window/tab and is temporary, unlike `localStorage` which is more long term.

You can even set a time/date stamp to determine how old the data can get before it is considered stale and needs refreshed.